# In redux toolkit, a function created using `createAsyncThunk` is not getting invoked when called using `dispatch`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here is a my setup. In my `feature.tsx` I have the following:

```
import { fetchHistory } from "./featureSlice"
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../app/hooks"

...

const featureData = useAppSelector(selectFeatureData)

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('one')
  dispatch(fetchFeature({}))
  console.log('three')
}, [])

...

{ featureData && <span>{JSON.stringify(featureData)}<span/> }
```

In the `featureSlice.ts` file

```
export const fetchFeature = createAsyncThunk('feature/data', async (args: any, { getState }) => {
  console.log('two')
  return axios.get...
})
```

In the console, I see 'one', 'three', but not 'two' any idea why? What am I missing?

The funny thing is I have another `createAsyncThunk` and that is getting invoked correctly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Argh! turns out in my `extraReducers` I had the following.

```
      .addCase(fetchFeature.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
        state.feature = action.payload.data
      })
      .addCase(fetchFeature.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle'
      })
      .addCase(fetchFeature.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle'
        state.feature = ''
      })
```

Can you spot the issue?

Yup! This line should've been inside `fetchFeature.fulfilled` block, instead of `fetchFeature.pending`

```
state.feature = action.payload.data
```

*Note to self:* Do **not** disable `Redux DevTools`